# Preciso de ajuda com uma macro do Solidworks

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6, vbs

Basicamente ela tem que abrir o desenho 2d de um arquivo selecionado da montagem gerar o PDF e fechar, consegui alguma coisa, mas só funciona com o arquivo do caminho, não sei qual comando usar para que ela funcione com qualquer arquivo que escolher.

```
' ******************************************************************************
' C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\swx9936\Macro1.swb - macro recorded on 06/29/16 by Home
' ******************************************************************************
Dim swApp As Object

Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()

Set swApp = _
Application.SldWorks


Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("PLACA BASE SUPERIOR-1@MOLDE HÉLICE", "COMPONENT", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
Set Part = swApp.OpenDoc6("D:\PROJETOS SOLIDWORKS\PAULINHO FERRAMENTARIA\MOLDE HELICE-2\PLACA BASE SUPERIOR.SLDDRW", 3, 0, "", longstatus, longwarnings)



Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
swApp.ActivateDoc2 "PLACA BASE SUPERIOR - Sheet1", False, longstatus

''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim FilePath As String
Dim PathSize As Long
Dim PathNoExtention As String
Dim NewFilePath As String

FilePath = Part.GetPathName
PathSize = Strings.Len(FilePath)
PathNoExtention = Strings.Left(FilePath, PathSize - 6)
NewFilePath = PathNoExtention & "pdf"


Part.SaveAs2 NewFilePath, 0, True, False

Set Part = Nothing
swApp.CloseDoc "PLACA BASE SUPERIOR - Sheet1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Eu não sei o que é Soliworks, por isso resolvi comentar ao invés de simplesmente editar diretamente. Faz mesmo sentido ter as tags [tag:vba] e [tag:visual-basic-6] na pergunta? VBA e VB *não são* a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Use "**Application.FileDialog**", consulte o **link** abaixo.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff836226.aspx

Usei de um botão para acionar a rotina.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UseFileDialogOpen

End Sub
```

Segue o código que consta no **link** citado:

```
Sub UseFileDialogOpen()

    Dim lngCount As Long

    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

        ' Display paths of each file selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount)
        Next lngCount

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @user49704, não era isso que precisava? Aqui no Soft, mesmo que a resposta não seja a solução mas "foi útil" de alguma forma, ela é marcada (abaixo das setas à esquerda do topo da resposta, e também a própria resposta e outras que venham a ser apresentadas podem receber o seu voto (setas), indicando aos demais do interesse ou utilidade gerado pela resposta. Se for o caso, por favor, marque a resposta.